# Simple if else in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

How to implement simple if else condition in rails

PHP : `echo $params = isset($_POST['some_params']) ? $_POST['some_params'] : "";`

RAILS : ??

Thanks,

Comment: `p params[:some_params]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into Ruby Ternary operator: A good source is http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

```
params[:some_params].present? ? 'a' : 'b'
```

another way of doing this is:

```
if params[:some_params].present?
  ....
else 
  ....
end
```

> There is one more operator called Ternary Operator. This first
>   evaluates an expression for a true or false value and then execute one
>   of the two given statements depending upon the result of the
>   evaluation. The conditional operator has this syntax:

Comment: hi MZaragoza, it's work. thanks for your information.

Comment: Glad that I could help Happy Hacking